# Docker ENTRYPOINT using docker run command

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running below command to set entrypoint through command line to start nginx service with this container

root@server:~#  docker run -it  --entrypoint="/bin/bash /root/service.sh"  docker-reg.bu-aws.nl:5000/ubuntu:v3  bash

root@server:~# cat /root/service.sh

## !/bin/bash

service nginx start
while true; do sleep 1d; done

so is it possible with docker run command or i need to define Dockerfile only

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Entrypoint script must placed inside continer.

Comment: my question is i want to run nginx service through docker run command so above scenario  is possible or not

Comment: @ Bukharov Sergey : can you give me syntax for above  scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the ENTRYPOINT instruction at the end of your Dockerfile.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/root/service.sh"]
```

Of course, you'll need to add the service.sh to your image. Again using a Dockerfile

```
COPY service.sh /root/service.sh
```

In the end it will be something like this.

```
FROM docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/ubuntu:v3

COPY service.sh /root/service.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/root/service.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks but will do same thing with docker run command instead of Dockerfile if yes then how

Comment: Thanks now i understand the logic

Answer (score 0):

To change the entry point to bash use the following command:

```
sudo docker run --entrypoint "/usr/bin/bash" -it <any-other-options> <img>
```

Note: don't add bash at the end, as we use to do when using `-it`.